# JMeter : How to click on a particular element ?

Tags: testing, video, automation, jmeter

I am using using **JMeter** for load testing I am facing following problem:

I have a video creation website to test and i want to click on create and play video button by multiple users.

Answer (score 2):

This tutorial explain how to play actions in jmeter by many users, you must record action and then play it many time
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf
For more informations, jmeter can't register Javascript actions , it's only HTTP request.
To make sure that the action on your website will be captured in Jmeter proxy, you can use firebug with firefox, this is very helpful.