# JMeter How to record script for click on Skip button in a video shown on a web page in iframe tag

Tags: video, jmeter, video-recording

App I am testing has a You Tube video is embedded in the page with something as below:

```
<iframe id="test_video" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" title="YouTube video player" width="349" height="196" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/KwDUu9QodBc?autoplay=1&amp;controls=1&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Fclicktestenv.test.com&amp;id=1"></iframe>
```

There is a Skip button after the above  tag as below

```
      <div class="button_skip_10" onclick="skip_vid();" style="display: block; float: right;">Skip Vid</div>
```

I recorded the script by clicking on the Skup Vid button but JMeter script did not show anything recorded for this video nor not the Skip Vid button click.

Tried to record the script a couple of times but no luck!

Search did land me to the nearest related question at link below:
[JMeter : How to click on a particular element ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23364201/jmeter-how-to-click-on-a-particular-element)

But no solution yet.

Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JMeter : How to click on a particular element ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23364201/jmeter-how-to-click-on-a-particular-element)

Comment: recording is done on http level. If there's no http request upon lick of Skip video button, there won't be anything recorded. If you want to automate UI operations, look at selenium instead

Comment: i added sample code to indicate the situation. On Skip Vid button click there is a Javascript function called. Trying to do load test script that would simulate 1000 users are visiting the web page, video gets loaded, Skip button appears after 5 seconds, user clicks Skip Vid button and continues to next stuff on the page. So selenium webdriver script - I am not sure would be correct thing to use?

Comment: No luck so far. 
But now facing a challenge in the YouTube video itself not playing when i try to record a script using JMeter Proxy. It gives an error in the iframe section as
 "The webpage at https://www.youtube.com/embed/..blha.blha....myappdomain.com&widgetid=1 Might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address." 
However the the url plays OK when i remove JMeter 8888 proxy from browser.  
So, should I be recording this embedded YouTube video getting played in my website and doing load test at all?

Comment: I found this thread that recommends not to cover YouTube embedded video in load test. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26170268/jmter-constant-video-stream
Is that the best practice? End of the day end user is viewing it through my website though.